# Can I change the color of the text of my property when using mvvm?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm new here, so if there's anything I'm doing wrong or need to do differently, I'd love to hear it.

I have a property error message that I "binded" with the xmal. This property returns 2 strings. Either a message that something hasn't been entered or a calculation.
Can I give red with one and black with the other?

Thank you in advance,

[this is the method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KI1eh.png)

[Property](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LQFZB.png)

[xmal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UZhUn.png)

Comment: In the future it's best if you provide code as text in your question rather than images.

Comment: @GazTheDestroyer, why in the future? I'd say start now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `DataTrigger` inside a `Style` for the label.

```
<Label x:Name="lblFoutmelding" FontWeight="SemiBold" Content="{Binding Foutmelding" Grid.Row="3" Height="30" Margin="9 10 0 0">
    <Label.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Label">

            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>

            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Foutmelding}" Value="Gelieve de hoeveeleed in ta geven aub!">

                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>

                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>

        <Style>
   </Label.Style>
</Label>
```

Note that I have removed the black into a style setter, since setting it directly on the Label would override any style or trigger setters.

Also note that it would be **much** better to have a separate "Severity" property in your VM and trigger on that, rather than triggering on specific strings.

Comment: what exactly do you mean by severity property, how can I implement it?

Comment: Well, at a most basic level you could have a `public bool IsInError` which you set at the same time you set `Foutmelding`. Or an enum if you have more than two severities (eg info, warning, error) .Better would be to wrap these two properties into a proper `Melding` class.